# how to configure dns mapping in netgear router for local server

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, proxy, router

I have a server which act as a webserver in our LAN. its ip address is 192.168.137.70 and it has local domain name mapping with name "kf.kobo.local" in hosts file
[image]
I need to access the server from other laptops in the LAN using domain kf.kobo.local instead of ipaddress.

What are the steps i need to take?

Answer (score 0):

As your web server IP address (192.168.137.70) is constant, providing you with steps for static Domain Name System server.If you want to go with a Dynamic Domain Name System(DDNS) then refer to the detailed steps provided [here](https://kb.netgear.com/23860/How-do-I-set-up-a-NETGEAR-Dynamic-DNS-account-on-my-NETGEAR-Nighthawk-router) .
DDNS service automatically updates the IP address information that is assigned to your host (domain) name.

To set static DNS servers on your NETGEAR router:

- Launch a web browser from a PC that is connected
  to your NETGEAR router.
- Visit [www.routerlogin.net](https://www.netgear.com/home/services/routerlogincom/).
- Enter the username and password.
  The default username is admin. The default password is password.
- Select the Internet. The Internet Setup page displays.
- Under the Domain Name Server (DNS) Address section, select the radio
  button for Use these DNS Servers.
- Enter your primary DNS and secondary DNS addresses.
  If you do not know your primary and secondary DNS addresses, contact your ISP for assistance.
- Click Apply.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is local network and there is no internet. What DNS primary address can i give. Are we making router as dns server following the above steps.

Comment: A DNS server (bind9) was installed in the ubuntu server machine and problem solved